# My text is not centering inside a li container

Tags: html, css

I am tearing my hair out trying to center the text right in the middle of the li container. It seems like it centers left to right. But top to bottom it is not.

I have tried to add a span to the text and move it via the margin, and padding. I have been unsuccessful to move the text at all.

I expect the text to be centered horizontally and vertically right in the center of the blue box. Right now, the text is centered left to right, but not centered top to bottom.

````
<html>

<style>
.follow-button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #0081F2;
    border: #0081F2;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.follow-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    bacgkround: #0059D0;
    border-color: #0059D0;
  }

#follow-button-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
</style>

<ul id="follow-button-nav">
    <li class="follow-button">Follow</li>
 </ul>

</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't centered the height of text except :

- You making adjusment with top and botton padding
- Making the div inside td and change the vertical-align to middle

thought they are many disucssion of this problem, you should search more. It's 2019

Edit :

And i'm forgot about line height. Althought it's not recomended. You can just add the line-height css on the button.

```
.follow-button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #0081F2;
    border: #0081F2;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jq8o57cp/1/)

Comment: This is my second day trying to fix this problem. Perhaps I don't know what to type into the search bar. I did read quite a bit of threads, and couldn't find, or understand the answer. I always search myself before posting questions here.

Comment: You can add line-height on the css, i'm edit my answer

Comment: I appreciate it. That is exactly what I need. Just so I can grasp the concept, you say that there is no possible way to move the text via padding, or margin.up or down when it's inside a li container, or any container?

Comment: i am new in the html and css too (and what the worst my explaining skill with english is bad) , so i don't know if my description is correct. I don't say we can't move the text via padding. 

>> Yes we can, and the best way to making centered text inside div is making the padding top and bottom has the same number. Margin is the way centered the div or li (not text)

Comment: Interesting. Because I was having trouble moving the text via the padding. Maybe with time I will understand it. lol Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jq8o57cp/2/  here the fiddle of the problem fixed with making the top and bottom padding so the text can be centered.

Comment: i don't know why you accept Esger answer and not mine (based of your problem of the text and not centering the li), but glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do this:

```css
.follow-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #0081F2;
    border: #0081F2;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.follow-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #0059D0;
    border-color: #0059D0;
  }

#follow-button-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="follow-button-nav">
    <li class="follow-button">Follow</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This did the trick. Is there a reason why I couldn't move the text via the padding and margin? That's the only part that still has me a little confused. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You can do it with padding on the button as well, like `padding: 10px 0;`, but for an exact height of the button it's easier and shorter to set the line-height, i.c.w. vertical padding set to zero